# Checkbox says the value is always one even when unchecked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My html looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@quote) do |f| %>
  <div class="field" id="follow_up">
    <%= f.label "Follow up?" %>
    <%= f.check_box :follow_up %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller action contains this:

```
@quote.follow_up = :follow_up
```

The `follow_up` field is always updated as a 1 whether or not the checkbox was checked. How can I make it so `follow_up` is set as 0 if the box is unchecked and 1 if the box is checked?

Here is the schema (limited) of quotes table:

```
mysql> describe quotes;
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| created_at           | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| updated_at           | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| follow_up            | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| follow_up_date       | date          | NO   |     | 1970-01-01 |                |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

This is the MySql error I receive when running @Carl Markham's code:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'follow_up' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `quotes` (`quote_number`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `date`, `customer_id`, `dealerperson_id`, `shiptolocation_id`, `binmodel_id`, `bindescription`, `binprice`, `binmodel_quantity`, `quoted_by`, `quote_method`, `discount_percent`, `freightcharge_id`, `tax_percent`, `quoted_price`, `notes`, `fobandterm_id`, `price_year`, `last_user_initials`, `follow_up`) VALUES ('180706-050', '2018-07-06 16:53:44', '2018-07-06 16:53:44', '2018-07-06', 4251, 1, 500, 150, 'Hopper Bin - 4000 Bushel Capacity', 16090.0, 1, 'BK', 'mailed', 20.0, 4100, 5.0, 13515.6, '', 1, 2018, 'BK', NULL)
```

As you can see all the values has a value except for the last which is `NULL`.
This is the complete request:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vix6La7GcxEGxSrlRfEYvkuEAQddXGpZhn2NQ/HnT5ccACb5HB1hBds+mfbbEN6w+gMK7qQcV4hdkUsJ7uq3OA==",
 "quote"=>
  {"date"=>"2018-07-06",
   "quoted_price"=>"$12872.00",
   "notes"=>""
   "follow_up"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that is wrong in your code was:

```
# Controller
@quote.follow_up = :follow_up
```

You are assigning a `Symbol` to the attribute `follow_up` here. You need to access the value from `params` instead. Replace above statement with:

```
@quote.follow_up = params[:quote][:follow_up] == '1'
```

Comparison operator [`==`](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/operators/comparison.html) always returns a `Boolean` value. So, this will always set `follow_up` to `true` or `false`.

**Improvement:** If you want to prevent a `NULL` value being saved in attribute `follow_up`, it's better that you detect it at model level. Add a validation in model for that. Something like:

```
# Model Quote (or whatever)
validates :follow_up, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

It will add a nice error message to the `@quote` object instead of just throwing a MySQL error.

Comment: That's great ! how did you come to know that `follow_up` is boolean type column? and you just converted 1 and 0 to true or false for that? just a bit confusion .

Comment: That was *one* assumption i made.

Answer (score 0):

It's because what you are doing here

`@quote.follow_up = :follow_up`

Is setting the value of `follow_up` to the symbol `:follow_up`

I assume the `follow_up` field in the database is set to an integer, that's why it is always 1 in your case (the symbol is a thruthy value).

What you need to do is get the value from the params

```
@quote.follow_up = params[:follow_up]
```

If the param is there, the checkbox was checked. If it's not there, the checkbox wasn't checked.

Comment: When I try this it tries to insert a Null value which throws an error because `follow_up` can only be 0 or 1.

Comment: `@quote.follow_up = params[:quote][:follow_up]` but it is better to whitelist `follow_up` and update/create from the whitelist.

Comment: Still tries to insert NULL